# gradle Error: "You must set the property 'aspectjVersion' before applying the aspectj plugin" when using kotlin DSL

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I want to configure aspectJ plugin in my gradle project which is using kotlin DSL.

Below is my `build.gradle.kts` file.

```
    val aspectjVersion = "1.9.3"

    plugins {
        java
        id("aspectj.gradle") version "0.1.6"
    }

    group = "java-agents-demo"
    version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation("org.aspectj","aspectjrt", aspectjVersion)
        implementation("org.aspectj","aspectjweaver", aspectjVersion)
        testCompile("junit", "junit", "4.12")
    }

    configure<JavaPluginConvention> {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

When I run `compileJava` project I get error "You must set the property 'aspectjVersion' before applying the aspectj plugin".

I set `aspectjVersion` in my build file but I don't know what is the error in it.

Can anyone help me setup the aspectJ plugin for my project in correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `val aspectjVersion = "1.9.3"` defines a local variable, but the plugin is looking for a project property, note that this also means the plugin can't be applied straight away as the plugins block is evaluated before the rest of the `build.gradle.kts` (see [limitations of plugin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#plugins_dsl_limitations)), try this instead:

```
val aspectjVersion by extra("1.9.3")

plugins {
    java
    id("aspectj.gradle") version "0.1.6" apply false
}

apply(plugin = "aspectj.gradle")
```

See Gradle docs on [extra properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html#sec:extra_properties) for details.

Comment: @RajkumarNatarajan I edited the answer to show a more complete example; basically due to how the plugins DSL works this plugin can't be applied immediately as it then checks for this property before the rest of `build.gradle.kts` is evaluated and so before this property is set.

Answer (score 3):

You can also define `aspectjVersion=1.9.5` in your `gradle.properties` file as this is loaded prior to the plugins.  This works for Gradle 7 compatibility, too.